# Npm not open correctly

Tags: node.js, npm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j8nJ.png)

The NPM function should be like when I write NPM install firebase and then the firebase should be installed when I write that command but in this situation when I write that command or anything using the NPM command the result is the file is doesn't download or do nothing instead of that the command ask to open some file by choosing the type of file. I have done anything to fix this problem but nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run

```
npm init
```

Beside that add to your question exactly the line you run and the error you get.

Comment: the error I get is only that when type that command nothing function

Comment: If you want to install fire base this is the command: npm install --save firebase

Comment: If you want npm to recognize your local package, you have to upload it to npm registry: https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-scoped-public-packages